# Index Match with updated value by date range

Tags: excel, office365

I have two tables:

1. Table with a list of sales with 3 parameters:
   CustomerID, Country and date of purchase.
2. Table with prices and Date range for each price

I want to see the updated price for each sale based on the date range of the price.
How Can I do that?

I want to see 1100$ for the first sale and 1200$ to the 2nd sale

[image: Table2]

[image: Table1]

Comment: probably with SUMIFS or FILTER or MAXIFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Formula is:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$3;$A$2:$A$3;G2;$B$2:$B$3;H2;$D$2:$D$3;"<="&I2;$E$2:$E$3;">="&I2)
```

The tricky part here is the date criteria: your purchase date must be greater or equal to `From Date` and must be also lower or equal than `To Date`. Following that logic can help you out to track the price on a exact time period, country and client.

Answer (score 0):

Providing your `Price From Date` column is in ascending order you can use INDEX/MATCH:  `=INDEX($C$2:$C$3,MATCH(D6,$D$2:$D$3,1))`

The `1` in the `MATCH` function tells it to "find the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value.  Lookup_array must be placed in ascending order."

[image]